# why wont my htaccess redirect work?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I and trying to get our site to redirect to an asset library.  So hexarmor.com/library should redirect to `http://209.62.107.135/cgi-bin/ImageFolio43/imageFolio.cgi` instead you are delivered to `http://209.62.107.135/cgi-bin/ImageFolio43/imageFolio.cgi/?/library/`

The addition of `/library/` throws a 500 server error.  Why is this variable being passed with my redirect and how can I remove it?  I have included my entire htaccess below.  Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /library http://209.62.107.135/cgi-bin/ImageFolio43/imageFolio.cgi
Redirect 301 /library/ http://209.62.107.135/cgi-bin/ImageFolio43/imageFolio.cgi

RewriteCond $1 !.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

FileETag MTime Size
ExpiresActive On
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"
</FilesMatch>

# gzip on Apache 2
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript application/xhtml+xml application/javascript

# these browsers do not support deflate
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue through the help of my cousin. Figured I would post in efforts to help future visitors with a similar problem.

For reference

```
Redirect 301 /library http://209.62.107.135/cgi-bin/ImageFolio43/imageFolio.cgi
Redirect 301 /library/ http://209.62.107.135/cgi-bin/ImageFolio43/imageFolio.cgi
```

Were changed to

```
RewriteRule ^library$ "http\:\/\/209\.62\.107\.135\/cgi\-bin\/ImageFolio43\/imageFolio\.cgi" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^library/$ "http\:\/\/209\.62\.107\.135\/cgi\-bin\/ImageFolio43\/imageFolio\.cgi" [R=301,L]
```

Changed the redirects to rewrite rules than set the 301 redirect flag at the end.

```
[R=301,L]
```

The destination url is in quotes and escaped with the front-slashes.  Hope this helps.